# Get value from Property

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

```psh
$yourObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                "LastName"  = "Muster"
                "FirstName" = "Max"
              }
```

creates a property.

How can I access the value of the property so that a variable contains the first name or last name respectively?

Comment: Can you translate this?

Comment: I think you want to just use `$yourObject.LastName` and `$yourObject.FirstName`

Answer (score 0):

Object properties can be accessed via dot-notation, like in many other languages:

```psh
$surname   = $yourObject.LastName
$givenName = $yourObject.FirstName
```